# Dividing results from an activerecord query into two objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a rails-like way to divide results from an activerecord query?  For example, I did @results = Items.find(:all), but I want the top half of items from @results to appear in a line item under `<ul class="part1">`, and the other half of them to appear under `<ul class="part2">`.

```
<ul class="part1">
    <li><a href="#">result["name"]</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="part2">
    <li><a href="#">resultpart2["name"]</a></li>
</ul>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the in_groups method from ActiveSupport:

```
@grouped_results = @results.in_groups(2)
```

and iterate over `@grouped_results[0]` for part1 and `@grouped_results[1]` for part2.

Comment: Thanks, Greg!  I knew there would be a rails-like way to do this. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@results[0...@results.size/2] #part1
@results[(@results.size/2)..-1] #part2
```